# add user to an organizational unit in active directory

Tags: sharepoint, active-directory

I'm gonna build a webpart for creating user in active directory.

i want to add created user to an organizational unit if the organizational unit exist.

how i can do that?

Comment: What version of .NET are you on?? In 3.5, lots of things got a lot easier...

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you need to bind to the OU in question, and then call `.Children.Add()` to add the new user to that OU.

See this MSDN documentation for details:

- [Adding Directory Objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180851%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) shows how to add a group to the `Users` container - you should be able to convert that to your needs
- [Quick List of C# Directory Services samples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180833%28VS.80%29.aspx)
- [User Management with Active Directory](http://en.csharp-online.net/User_Management_with_Active_Directory%E2%80%94Creating_Users) shows sample code for exactly what you're looking for: adding a user to an organizational unit
- [How to do almost anything in Active Directory using C#](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/everythingInAD.aspx) is a great general resource showing how to do common tasks in Active Directory using C# and .NET